# Display HTML UL in a vertical direction

Tags: html, css

Normally i use ul to have list of product like this, just add "float: left" to the li and you are almost running:

```
p1 p2 p3 p4
p5 p6 p7 p8
```

Now i'm in the situation where i want it apposite like this:

```
p1 p4
p2 p6
p3 p7
p4 p8
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

The content in the p1 is dynamic and can be different in size(height). So I'm looking for something like a article layout. Etc: maybe there is only space for 3 product in the first list, and 4 in the next row. So i can't use something like two different list, because the content and product can change.

Comment: The easiest way is to break it up into two floating lists since `ul`s are already vertical by default.

Comment: Yes, that's called a `table` with 2 columns. :)

Comment: Can you add specific information about your use case? For example: Is the number of columns fixed? Or can it change when the window is resized? Would a JavaScript fix be acceptable? (and can jQuery be used?) Is there any server-side code involved in outputting the products? Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [CSS3 multi-column module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model) but it doesn't have widespread support yet (i.e. won't work in IE).

Comment: This is what i want http://kmsm.ca/2010/an-almost-complete-guide-to-css3-multi-column-layouts/ but how can i make it work in old browsers?

Comment: Probably need to use js as in this example: http://www.cvwdesign.com/txp/article/360/multi-column-layout-with-css3-and-some-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it this way. Nesting the columns in a `li` element.

**CSS:**

```
ul      { overflow:hidden }
li      { float:left }
li li   { float:none }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Column 1
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Column 2
        <ul>
            <li>Dolor</li>
            <li>Sit</li>
            <li>Amet</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>This text is not floated because the list has overflow set to 'hidden'.</p>
```

And if the content is dynamic, just let your script parse it into different lists.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    float:left;
}
.clearlist {
    clear:both;
    margin:0 410px 0 34px;  
 }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>p1</li>
    <li>p2</li>
    <li>p3</li>
    <li>p4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>p5</li>
    <li>p6</li>
    <li>p7</li>
    <li>p8</li>
</ul>

<div class="clearlist"></div>
```